# Replace multiple spaces with comma in Python

Tags: python, list, replace

I am reading switch output from file and would like to do something with values then.

If I read lines from file I have my data in following format with multiple spaces:

```
['Eth1/1         interfaceName connected  trunk      full     100G     QSFP-40/100-SRBD', 'Eth1/2         interfaceName2 connected  trunk      full     100G     QSFP-40/100-SRBD']
```

And I would need to delete those spaces and replace them with comma. So the output should be like when you read lines from .csv file:

```
['Eth1/1,interfaceName,connected,trunk,full,100G,QSFP-40/100-SRBD', 'Eth1/2,interfaceName2,connected,trunk,full,100G,QSFP-40/100-SRBD']
```

Any idea how to do it in simple way?

I have tried to iterate over each character in list and replace " " with "", but do not know how to enter one comma there.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `.split()` as it does split on one-or-more whitespace characters, then `.join` following way

```
text = "Able    Baker Charlie"
cleaned = ','.join(text.split())
print(cleaned)
```

gives output

```
Able,Baker,Charlie
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `re` module:

```py
import re

print(re.sub('\s+', ',', your_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Luddite answer: yes, repeatedly appending to a string is SLOOOW but, isn't it a Luddite answer?

```
In [60]: def spaces2comma(l0, prev_is_comma=False, l1=""):
    ...:     for c in l0:
    ...:         if c==" ":
    ...:             if prev_is_comma: continue
    ...:             else:c=",";prev_is_comma=1
    ...:         else:prev_is_comma=False
    ...:         l1+=c
    ...:     return l1
    ...: 
    ...: lines = ['Eth1/1    interfaceName    connected  trunk  full  100G  QSFP-40/100-SRBD',
    ...:          'Eth1/2    interfaceSurname connected  trunk  full  100G  QSFP-40/100-SRBD']
    ...: print(*(spaces2comma(l) for l in lines), sep='\n')
Eth1/1,interfaceName,connected,trunk,full,100G,QSFP-40/100-SRBD
Eth1/2,interfaceSurname,connected,trunk,full,100G,QSFP-40/100-SRBD

In [61]:
```

I forgot to mention:

```
In [61]: spaces2comma("    asde fgh   tyu", True)
Out[61]: 'asde,fgh,tyu'
```

Answer (score -1):

First use split() function to get a list of strings.

```
my_string = "'Eth1/1         interfaceName connected  trunk      full     100G     QSFP-40/100-SRBD', 'Eth1/2         interfaceName2 connected  trunk      full     100G     QSFP-40/100-SRBD'"
str = my_string.split()
```

Then join them using .join and use comma as seperator.

```py
new_string = ",".join(str)
```